# Given n vectors $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ in a real Hilbert space H, define the determinant of the $n\times n$ symmetric matrix

Tags: functional-analysis

[image]Given n vectors $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ in a real Hilbert space H, define their Gram determinant as the determinant of the $n\times n$ symmetric matrix in:
$G(v_1,\dots,v_n)=\left | \begin{matrix}
(v_1,v_1) &\cdots   & (v_n,v_1) \\
\vdots &\ddots & \vdots  \\
(v_1,v_n) & \cdots  &(v_n,v_n) \\
\end{matrix} \right | $
(i)Assuming that the vectors $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ are linear independent, consider the subspace $V=span\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$.For any vector $x\in H$,show that the distance of x to V is
$$d(x,V)=||x-P_V(x)||=\sqrt{\frac{G(x,v_1,\cdots,v_n)}{G(v_1,\cdots,v_n)}}$$
(ii)As shown in 5.8.1. prove that n-dimensional volume of the parallelepiped with edges $v_1,\dots,v_n$ can be expressed as
$$||v_1||\cdot d(v_2;span\{v_1\})\cdot d(v_3;span\{v_1,v_2\})\cdots d(v_n;span\{v_1,\cdots,v_{n-1}\})$$

Answer:(i)$v_1,\cdots,v_n$ are linear independent iff $G(v_1,\cdots,v_n)\neq 0$.If  $x\in H,y\in V$, then $G(x,v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n)=G(x+y,v_1,\dots,v_n)$.Taking $y=P_V(x)$ and $z=x-y=P_{V^{\perp}}(x)$, then we can obtain the proof. But my question is why $G(x,v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n)=G(x+y,v_1,\dots,v_n)$\
(ii) Via example of 2 dimensions and 3 dimensions (in the picture), I can conclude the formula of the n-dimensional volume of the parallelepiped, but I can't know how to prove the formula.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

1. Using the properties of the determinant, show that

$$G(x - \sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i, v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n) = G(x, x_1, \ldots, x_n)$$

2. For $\sum a_i v_i = P_V(x)$, we have

$$\langle x - P_V(x), v_i\rangle = 0$$
for all $1\le i \le n$. Conclude

3.

$$G(x- P_V(x), v_1, \ldots, v_n) = \langle x - P_V(x) , x - P_V(x)\rangle \cdot G(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer very much. I have more questions: first, about 1,I konw that $G(y,v_1,\dots,v_n)=0$, Do you mean that $G(x+y,v_1,\dots,v_n)=G(x,v_1,\dots,v_n)+G(y,v_1,\dots,v_n).$ Second, about(ii),how to prove the n-dimensional volume of the parallelepiped with edges $v_1,…,v_n.$